# 'twitter/bootstrap/responsive.less' wasn't found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, less

I am trying to move my application to another server, and I am currently getting the following error.

```
'twitter/bootstrap/responsive.less' wasn't found (in /home/rails/**/app/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less)
```

I don't have an :assets block in my gemfile -- so the previous solutions to this problem don't apply to my situation.

Here is my Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.1.1'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
#gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0'

# Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
gem 'spring'

#For User Management
gem 'devise'
gem 'cancan'
gem 'rolify'

#For adding attachments
gem 'paperclip', github: 'thoughtbot/paperclip'

#For Bootstrap
gem 'therubyracer'
gem 'less-rails'
gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'
gem 'bootstrap_form'

gem 'debugger'

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails'

# Use debugger
#gem 'debugger'
```

Any help is appreciated! I'm more or less clueless regarding this error.

Additional Note: My application functions properly on my current server, but I cannot get it to run even once on my new server and I have tried to install it identically.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I inadvertently ended up updating `twitter-bootstrap-rails` to 3.2.0 when I didn't specify a specific version in my gemfile. The previous version was at 2.2.8, which I rolled back to and everything works just fine now. The new version is missing the responsive.less file.

Comment: Bootstrap v3 has the responsiveness fully integrated, so there's no longer a separate `responsive.less` in v3.

Comment: When he says "roll back" he means in Gemfile: gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails', '2.2.8'

Comment: Unfortunately `bundle audit` reports [vulnerabilities](https://nvisium.com/blog/2014/03/28/reflected-xss-vulnerability-in-twitter/) in v2.2.8, and says to use >= 3.2.0.

Answer (score 9):

The set up for version 3.2.0 of twitter-bootstrap-rails is different from version 2.2.8.
If you want to use version 3.2.0 you must update the setup as well. To do so, run this command:

```
rails generate bootstrap:install less
```